# Why does Mathematica pop me into wolfram alpha sometimes (often) when I type an equal sign?

Tags: wolfram-alpha-notebook-edition

Why does Mathematica often pop me into wolfram alpha when I type an equal sign?
I should emphasize that the equal sign is not at the beginning of the expression, nor is it preceded by CTRL. It is thus not covered by any case described in the documentation.

I have since experienced more weird behaviors. Typing an asterisk at the end of a line suddenly converted the cell into an "Item."

Comment: See "Interactive Wolfram Language Input" under [`Free-Form & External Input`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FreeFormAndExternalInput.html) also [`Wolfram | Alpha Integration`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WolframAlphaIntegration.html)

Comment: Typing an equal sign at the start of line (or a double equal sign) both put you "outside" of Mathematica proper.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, but I am not typing the equal sign at the start of a line, nor am I typing == or CTRL =. So I don't think either of the previous replies answer the question.

Comment: under what circumstances does it occur? also, is it the case that you're using Wolfram|Alpha Notebook Edition, and not Mathematica, as the tag on this question suggests?

Comment: Using Mathematica 12.1.1.0, not Wolfram|Alpha Notebook Edition.

Comment: The circumstances are that I am entering an expression like "abc = " and after entering the equal sign it converts everything in the expression to a wolfram alpha thing

Comment: If you inadvertently have the `Control` key down when you type the `=` you will switch to natural language input.

Comment: I just experienced the same issue. It was within a `With` statement. Unfortunately I don't recall exactly what was I had written. Placing a space before the `=` "solved" the problem. This probably *is* a weird bug. Making it reproducible would be essential now.

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/225948/45431

Comment: @Natas does the Q&A linked by Carl Woll above describe the problem you experienced?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, thank you. I seem to run the "June 9" edition of 12.1.1.0. They seem to have a weird notion of version numbers...