# how do i stop the "=" symbol from creating "WolframAlphsShort"

Tags: input, keyboard

how do I stop the "=" symbol from creating "WolframAlphsShort."

Comment: It should only happen if you type = at the beginning of a line. There’s no valid Mathematica code that begins with = so it should be fine. If you’re getting it when typing = at other times, that’s a bug. I have had it happen to me on occasion in 12.1.1 but I have no idea what causes it.

Comment: @MassDefect Accidentally entering ctrl+=, perhaps?

Comment: @Alan I don’t think so. That just creates the free-form input which I often use in the middle of code, not the Wolfram Alpha input which affects the entire cell. When it happens, it’s also highly repeatable—I can undo the change, press = again, and it goes back to WA. If I paste the code into a new cell or re-type it, it’s fine and doesn’t do anything weird.

Comment: Most likely [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/225948/58370) problem.